# Use http or tcp request instead of a curl command

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, curl, httprequest

I've this curl commands:

```
curl.exe -s -X POST --cookie-jar c:\programdata\curl.cookies -F "username=X" -F "pwd=X" http://192.168.2.170/goform/UserLogin
curl.exe -s --cookie c:\programdata\curl.cookies --cookie-jar c:\programdata\curl.cookies -F 'secondi=1' -F 'decimi=0' -F 'outputNumber=1' http://192.168.2.170/goform/con_SetOutput
```

As for my understanding it first make the login on the remote device, and then pass to it a second request. How can I do the same avoiding curl and using only VS code behind solution (httpRequest or what's best in this kind of situations)? Thanks

Comment: I've done this, but it's been more than a decade so I can't be much help. I do remember needing to save a reference to a CookieContainer object to have it available for both steps.

Comment: I think you want to use the `System.Net.WebClient` type for this.  Here are the docs with examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-8.0

If you want to instead do this on the client site, you could do the same http request with JavaScript